# is there any way to collect some number into grid with one column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, selectcommand

I have a list  of numbers like this :
1,
2,
3,
4
and so on.
one way to make this list into grid with one column is union all.
is there another way to do that?
best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CROSS APPLY with STRING_SPLIT to achieve the same.

```sql
declare @table table(list varchar(50))
insert into @table values ('1, 2, 3, 4') 
select ss.value from @table as t
cross apply string_split(t.list,',') as ss
```

| value |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |